# How can I have PlotLegends showing the legend on a single line instead of two?

Tags: plotting, export, legending

I am using PlotLegends in a Plot command to label each line of my plot (it has 4 different functions plotted) but the legend is split in two lines. I would like it two appear in a single line so it has the same appearance as the other plots displayed next to it. Is there a way to do that? I guess reducing the font size would be an option but I don't know how to do it.

I don't know if this is relevant, but afterwards I export the plot to an EPS file using the command

```
Export["swp_c0.eps", c0plt]
```

so maybe increasing the resolution might solve my problem.

**UPDATE**

I reduced the font size and still couldn't get it in one line. However, when I changed my legend labels from scientific notation (10^-2, using the -2 as a superscript) to fixed point notation (0.01) it worked (with the reduced font size). Here there is the final result so I managed to get it working. However, I would like, if possible, to understand what was the problem.

[image: Plot how I want it (using fixed point notation).]

Comment: `PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "Row"]` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. Using "Column" displays them as a column but using "Row" doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post more details... maybe your plot as is

Answer (score 11):

You can use the option setting `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}` inside `LineLegend` to  have all legends in a single row:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[# x] & /@ Range[7]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Above]]
```

[image]

Or, use a custom function as the setting for this option to organize legends in a `Grid` with a single row:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[# x] & /@ Range[7]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", 
    LegendLayout -> (Grid[{Flatten@Riffle[#, Spacer[3]]}] &)], Above]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Place the legends `Above | Top` or `Below | Bottom`, e.g.,

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you run `InputForm@Plot[...][[2]]`, you'll notice that this sets `LegendLayout -> "Row"`. :)